# List files with 'ls' that have at least two vowels in linux shell

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-interface, ls

I'm stuck with this problem:

> List all files with ls that have at least two vowels in any position and
> end with .c, .h or .s

I have come with a partial solution : `ls *{a,e,i,o,u}*.[chs]`

But obviously this does not fulfill the problem requirements because it list all files that have any numbers of vowel, not two or more.

Comment: I don't think globs support this, I would pipe the ls through egrep to filter also  with a regexp

Comment: Globs *do* support (an equivalent of) this. Just switch `extglob` on, which is mostly on by default for interactive shells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a character class for the vowels, too

```
ls *[aeiou]*[aeiou]*.[chs]
```

Using the bracket expansion is possible, too, but some files are then listed multiple times:

```
ls *{a,e,i,o,u}*{a,e,i,o,u}*.[chs]
```

Comment: I suggest to add `shopt -s nullglob` for your second command.

Comment: Keep in mind that the braces *create* multiple patterns which then have to be expanded, rather than being part of a single pattern. `*{a,e,i,o,u}*`, for example, is short for `*a* *e* *i* *o* *u*`.